# How to add TextArea while clicking on image using React JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

###This is how the code looks like ###

```
const message = () => {
  console.log("Hello World!") 
 }

return(
<label htmlFor="myInput" ><ShoppingBagIcon style={{width:'26px'}} type="shoppingbag" /></label>
 <input id="myInput" type="text" style={{display:'none'}}  onClick={message} />)}

export default message
```

Comment: Do you want to "show" a single `TextArea` or add multiple?

Comment: I want to add a single TextArea

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hook `const [shown, setShown] = useState(false)`
and render the `TextArea` based on the value of the hook.

An oversimplified example:

```js
  const [shown, setShown] = useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <button on:click={() => setShown(!shown)}/>
      {shown ? <TextArea/> : <WithoutTextArea/>}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra state say, toggleView in your project. And when a user clicks the image you can set the value true or false. Based on that you can show the textField or not. What I meant is

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const message = () => {
  const [showText,toggleShowText] = useState(false);
    console.log("Hello World!") 
  const toggleTextField = () => toggleShowText(!showText)
   
  
  return(
    <div>

      <label htmlFor="myInput" ><ShoppingBagIcon style={{width:'26px'}} type="shoppingbag" onClick ={()=>toggleShowText(!showText)}/></label>
      {
      showText ? (
      <input id="myInput" type="text" onClick={message} />
      ) : (<div/>)
      }
      </div>
   );
  
  }
  
  export default message;
```

Also in your code, the curly braces are not formatted, I did that Above example.

Also, you can use the ternary operator inside the HTML tag.

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" style={showText ? {display:'none'}: {display:'inline'}}  onClick={message} />
```

or

```
style={{display: showText ? 'block' : 'none'}}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using that but its showing the  error : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: toggleTextField

Comment: don't forget to import {useState} from 'react' , I guess it's ovbious

Comment: I have added that as well, but then too its showing that error

Comment: okay. then add this line onClick ={()=>toggleShowText(!showText)}

Comment: Then it shows this another errorReferenceError: Can't find variable: showText

Comment: okay. Now we are getting somewhere. You have to return a <div> component when returning so wrap the whole HTML code in a div tag. I've also updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best way of doing hiding or showing an HTML element is using `ref`

1. import `useRef` from react

```
import { useRef } from "react";
```

2. Create a ref

```
const inputRef = useRef();
```

3. Use it in the input or textarea

```
<input
  ref={inputRef}
  id="myInput"
  type="text"
  style={{ display: "none" }}
/>
```

4. Now you can change it's any style like this

```
inputRef.current.style.display = "block";
```

**Why ref?**

Because it do not re-render the component. If you use state it will cost a render but using ref it won't

here is the [solve](https://codesandbox.io/s/sws-08131906-lxvyk)

**Updated**

If you want to hide any elements you can do that like this bellow

```
ref_variable.current.style.display = 'none'
```

So when and which element you want to hide just make the display none using the ref.

For example if you want to hide the textarea after input. Just do that.

Comment: Hi, thank you .But, when I apply that as it contains image as you can see in my code, while clicking on the image  it displays the pop up with image as well as text. Could you please suggest me how to resolve that so that while clicking on that image it should only pop up the text area area and after entering the value it hides as well.

Comment: Updated the answer. if you want more clarification please create a codesandbox and share it I will solve there.